# Can't get this AJAX to work for my form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this registration form:

```
<div id="sign_up_field">
        <form id="sign_up_form" action="sys/account/sign_up.php" name="sign_up" method="post">
            <input class="account_form" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name (first and last name)" />
            <input class="account_form" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email address" />
            <input class="account_form" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
            <input class="account_form" type="text" name="username" placeholder="@username" />
            <input class="account_button" id="sign_up_button" type="submit" value="Sign up" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here's the JS (JQuery):

```
<script>
/*
* AJAX sign up
*/
$("#sign_up_button").click(function() {
    $.post( $("#sign_up_form").attr("action"),
            $("#sign_up_form :input").serializeArray(),
            function(info) {

                $('body').empty();
                $('body').html(info);

            });

    $("#sign_up_form").submit( function() {
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm a rookie with AJAX, it's my first try from a Youtube tutorial, but when I hit the submit button it just takes me straight to sign_up.php. The PHP code works, but the JS doesn't seem to do what it should do. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Add a e.preventDefault(); to the beginning of your listener; be sure to add e as a parameter passed to the function, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If code is placed before the form within the page, it won't find the elements because they don't exist yet. Wrapping the code in `ready()` will fix that

Also the submit handler is better bound to the form prior to the click on the button. Personally I would bind the ajax to the submit handler. Then if user hits "enter" instead of click on button it will still go through ajax

Try this:

```
$(function(){ /* ready handler*/   
    $("#sign_up_form").submit( function() {
        /* do ajax here */
        return false;
    });    
});
```

**[jQuery.ready() docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**

Comment: @user3608176 check browser console for errors. `doesn't work` isn't very informative. WHat does or doesn't happen?

Comment: The console only gives two errors, but none of those have anything to do with my AJAX code.

Comment: but errors can block other code from running and perhaps submit handler isn't even being applied